# mySQL: compute user reputation from comments table and update users table

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables: `comments`

```
CommentID   UserID  Score
1           10      -5
2           10      2
3           11      3
4           11      0
5           12      2
```

... and `users`

```
UserID  CommentsReputation
10      0
11      0
```

I'm having trouble coming up with one efficient MySQL query that will set each user's `CommentsReputation` in the 2nd table to be the sum of all scores for comments belonging to that user. The challenge is that the only input I have with which to build the query is the `CommentID` (meaning I don't know the `UserID` at the code location where the query will be executed).

For example, given `CommentID=3`, I want to add up all the scores for `UserID 11` and set that user's `CommentsReputation` to `3+0+2`

Here is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE `user` u SET u.`CommentsReputation` = (
    SELECT SUM(c.`Score`) FROM `comments` c
    WHERE c.`UserID`= (
      SELECT c2.`UserID` FROM `comments` c2
      WHERE c2.`CommentID`= 3
    )
)
```

This will correctly select the sum of scores belonging to user #11, but it does not update the correct row in the `users` table

I know I could split this into one query to select the `UserID` at `CommentID=3`, and a second query with knowledge of the `UserID`. Hoping for a more efficient approach.

Comment: This has a bad smell. You shouldn't be storing data that can be derived from other columns.

Comment: @shmosel Looking for efficiency. I intend to use it as a trigger; whenever `Score` gets updated, `CommnentsReputation` is also updated in an attempt to reduce the computation time of later queries that rely on reputation. Reputation will also be queried every couple of minutes so I thought instead of computing it again for all users every time, I would just store the result of the computation and change the result when the dependent variable is updated. Perhaps I should rethink this.

Comment: Are your tables very big? It might be simpler to update all the users at once.

Comment: Probably wouldn't be considered very big by MySQL standards. Tens of thousands of rows for each table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE users u
  JOIN (
      SELECT UserID, SUM(Score) AS TotalScore
        FROM comments
       WHERE UserID = (SELECT UserID FROM comments WHERE CommentID = 3)
     ) c ON c.UserID = u.UserID
   SET u.CommentsReputation = c.TotalScore;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0c5ee/1/0)

If you want to update all the users at once, you can use a similar subquery with a `GROUP BY`:

```
UPDATE users u
  JOIN (
      SELECT UserID, SUM(Score) AS TotalScore
        FROM comments
       GROUP BY UserID
     ) c ON c.UserID = u.UserID
   SET u.CommentsReputation = c.TotalScore;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4cbe7/1/0)

Comment: Thank you @shmosel. I didn't know that we could perform Insert, Update or Delete operations on the result of JOINs, since these tables exist only in memory. PS: if you have the time, please show an alternative query that would update all records in the `users` table, instead of just the record whose user matches the targeted `CommentID`.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Updated.